# How to add a title and Data Source Link in gvisSankey Diagram in R

Tags: r

```
    UCS_final <- gvisSankey(data, from = 'Var1', to = 'Var2', 
                 weight = 'Freq', options = list(height = 800, width = 1600, title = "Sankey")
```

Comment: title="Sankey" not working

Comment: have a look at [these examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html) or if possible make [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question.